# Как установить фигуру в центр и отмаштабировать ее?

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

Как установть фигуру в центр GLCtonrol`а? Использую SharpGL в WPF проекте.

Рендерю треугольник:

```
private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, SharpGL.SceneGraph.OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        OpenGL gL = GLControl.OpenGL;

        gL.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        gL.LoadIdentity();

        maxX = Math.Max(AX, Math.Max(BX, CX));
        maxY = Math.Max(AY, Math.Max(BY, CY));
        minX = Math.Min(AX, Math.Min(BX, CX));
        minY = Math.Min(AX, Math.Min(BX, CX));
        maxZ = Math.Max(AZ, Math.Max(BZ, CZ));
        minZ = Math.Min(AZ, Math.Min(BZ, CZ));

        double figureWidht = maxX - minX;
        double figureHeight = maxY - minY;
        double figureSquare = figureWidht * figureHeight;


        double viewPortSquare = GLControl.Width * GLControl.Height;

        gL.Translate(-figureWidht / 2, -figureHeight / 2, -6);//-6 - произвольное число

        gL.Begin(OpenGL.GL_LINES);
        gL.Color(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
        gL.Vertex((float)AX, (float)AY, (float)AZ);
        gL.Vertex((float)BX, (float)BY, (float)BZ);
        gL.Vertex((float)BX, (float)BY, (float)BZ);
        gL.Vertex((float)CX, (float)CY, (float)CZ);
        gL.Vertex((float)CX, (float)CY, (float)CZ);
        gL.Vertex((float)AX, (float)AY, (float)AZ);
        gL.End();

    }
```

Как сделать, чтобы фигура всегда была в центре? Вне зависимости от ее вершин? 
А если фигура выходит за грани viewport`а, то сделать ее меньше и поместить в центр?

Объясняю на кртинке:
[image: что нужно]

Comment: Не похоже, что на второй картинке справа треугольник прям в центре, т.к. внизу больше отступ чем сверху. Т.ч. вам необходимо более точно сформулировать требование - "Поместить в центр"

Comment: @Unick на второй фотографии показанно маштабирование, которое мне нужно. Вообще мне нужно подгонять фигуру так, чтобы снизу, сверху, справа и слева был одинаковый отступ. Не одинаковый сразу по всем сторонам. а иммено для верха и низа одинаковый и для левой и правой стороны аналогично. Лево и право отдельно от верха и низа. И если фигура выходит за грани viewport`а, поместить ее в этот viewport как на воторой картинке. Сделал заново - https://imgur.com/a/5Q0ej8y , может так будет понятнее...

Comment: Математически задача выглядит как: нахождения ограничивающего прямоугольника для фигры и вписание его. При условии, что центр вашей фиругы в её геометрическом центре. А потом просто рассчитать сдиг и масштаб.

Comment: @Unick сдивг я рассчитал -   
`double figureWidht = maxX - minX;
double figureHeight = maxY - minY;
gL.Translate(-figureWidht / 2, -figureHeight / 2, -6);`. Все работает идеально. А вот как масштаб рассчитать - не знаю.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример кода с вашими вычислениями в вопросе, т.к. сейчас он кажется не полный

Comment: @Unick обновил вопрос.